# how to properly inject type of an method or property to before mixin a given SuperClass in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, mixins

In the example below, the type of method is not properly found in the class passed by parameter as superclass to the mixin function:

```js
type Constructor = new (...args: any[]) => {};

function ClassMixin<TBase extends Constructor>(Base: TBase) {
    return class extends Base {
        method() {
            console.log("method method method method");
        }
    }
}

const MyClass = ClassMixin(class Z {
    constructor() {
        this.method(); // NOT OK: Property 'method' does not exist on type 'Z'
    }
});

const z = new MyClass();

z.method(); // <---- ok
```

[playground example](https://www.staging-typescript.org/play?ssl=19&ssc=24&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gOwM7AE4FcDGw6qgXigQgHcoAKAOmoENUBzJALihoRAG0BdASgID4oAbwC%20AbgBQEgGboE2AJaJYAGxpIkAWQUAPBQgA8AFQBC66BB3AICACZJYiFBmy5%205M0ggtT5vkIkoIKhUCGB0VAQoTDUNKEtrOwdPaADg9KgAWzCACzhbcn9AjJLMJzgVCEoVOHpyACJs4DzbLNz8tuaOppb6nkkSoJFioYlhiTLkYChNEBhYh0J59S1dfXIYlagALWER6Kc0LBxUQr3BqGaFJEoe-MKxKAB6J6gAOQB5IygPgGkWAAKqDgkFQoCgAHI7rYIVBbHAIA4EHBppZrtNlKBIJDthD9sMRP0pJMUFAAF4EIikGZzBYPKRk27tAr9Z6vAwAWi5HKgcAA1kA)

---

I found a work-around to make it work, but I'm searching for a more 'automatic' solution, check the work-around below:

```js
type Constructor = new (...args: any[]) => {};

function ClassMixin<TBase extends Constructor>(Base: TBase) {
    return class extends Base {
        method() {
            console.log("method method method method");
        }
    }
}

interface ClassMixinInterface {
    method(): void
}

interface Z extends ClassMixinInterface { }

class Z {
    constructor() {
        this.method(); // <---- ok
    }
}

const MyClass = ClassMixin(Z);

const z = new MyClass();

z.method(); // <---- ok
```

[playground work-around example](https://www.staging-typescript.org/play?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=27&pc=24#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gOwM7AE4FcDGw6qgXigQgHcoAKAOmoENUBzJALihoRAG0BdASgID4oAbwC+AbgBQEgGboE2AJaJYAGxpIkAWQUAPBQgA8AFQBC66BB3AICACZJYiFBmy5+5M0ggtT5vkIkoIKhUCGB0VAQoTDUNKEtrOwdPaADg9KgAWzCACzhbcn9AjJLMJzgVCEoVOHpyACJs4DzbLNz8tuaOppb6nkkSoJFioYlhiX1rVGkaTGgYWK1dfQBJBCmZueERzpbClgA3OAVbMalJiGnZ6AAteKsbe1V1Jb0ENY3r4ShxmJeoO5pYJlZBoLA4VCFbaDKDNBRISg9fKFMRQAD0aKgBgAtLjsVA4ABrHbDX5OYBQTQgBb-Qg0jTaN7kG79KQglBQABeBCIpEp1MWKKknMR7QK-XRmJxeIJhKAA)

Comment: Your work-around might be as good as it gets.  In general with mixins I use a generic constructor so that I can declare properties and methods which must exist on a `TBase` class: `type Constructor<T> = new (...args: any[]) => T;`  But that doesn't help here because your issue is the circular nature of the code.  `class Z` needs to know that it will be mixed (and get a `this.method`) before you apply the mixin to it.